# Is the process,repeated tosses of a fair die,WSS?

Tags: probability-theory, correlation, stationary-processes

If X[n] is a discrete random process , which is  repeated tosses of a fair die,is X[n] a WSS process?I know that E[X[n]] is $\frac{7}{2}$,but I am not very sure that $E[X[n+\tau]]$ is also $\frac{7}{2}$ to let this process not WSS,can anyone tell me what the $E[X[n+\tau]] $ is or is this process a WSS?

Comment: Why do you think that the expectation of the process would change or is different from any other time, given the dice is fair?

Comment: yes you are right,so this process shouldn't be WSS?I think yes

Comment: It seems so, but then why would you want to find this information out?

Comment: curiosity，I wonder that for a process,which is equally likely,is it possible a WSS?because its mean is a constant,satisfy one of WSS conditions